# Novice's question: I don't want other objects' locations to move when I add a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

TikZ novice, here. I want to create two slides (in Beamer), identical except for the addition of a circle in the second slide. I don't want the addition of the circle to shift about the placement of the other objects on the page, which is what currently happens. Suggestions?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames, professionalfonts,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,arrows}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\draw (8,1) circle [radius=1.081];

\draw[fill] (15.5,0) circle [radius=0.05];

\draw (8,-2) circle [radius=1.08];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
}

\frame{
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]


\draw (8,1) circle [radius=1.081];

\draw[fill] (15.5,0) circle [radius=0.05];

\draw (8,-2) circle [radius=1.08];


\draw[dashed] (15.5,0) circle [radius=7.515];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way is to draw the bigger circle in a `scope` with the option `overlay`. From the [TikZ/PGF manual](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf):

> The effect of [`overlay`] is that everything within the current scope is not taken
>   into consideration when the bounding box of the current picture is computed.

### Edit:

If the other contents of the two slides are the same, you can simplify your code by using the Beamer overlay specification (unfortunately, the Beamer overlay is different from the TikZ overlay): simply add a Beamer overlay specification `<2->` to the `\draw` command of the bigger circle (this means that the bigger circle will only be shown from the second slide onwards)

One more note: it's not necessary to load the `graphics` package, because TikZ automatically loads [`graphicx`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/grfguide.pdf)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames, professionalfonts,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,arrows}

\begin{document}

\frame{

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\draw (8,1) circle [radius=1.081];

\draw[fill] (15.5,0) circle [radius=0.05];

\draw (8,-2) circle [radius=1.08];

\begin{scope}[overlay]
  \draw<2->[dashed] (15.5,0) circle [radius=7.515];
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than mine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `tikz` automatically adjusts the bounding box of each picture to the coordinates used in that picture.  When you add the large circle, you change the bounding box for that picture. But you can use any particular `\draw` command as the bounding box, so you should add that to use the smaller circles to define the bounding box for both images.

I removed the `figure` environment from your code on the assumption that  it is  inappropriate to use in `beamer` generally, since it is a floating environment, and you don't want material to float in a presentation. However, as Gonzalo notes in the comments, it is actually ok to leave such floating environments in a presentation especially if you are also using the same `beamer` code to produce an article version of your presentation. It will also allow you to use captions.  Beamer deactivates the floating property  in presentation mode.  If that's not your intention, however, there's really no need to use floats in a presentation.

Please note that I consider KevinC's answer the more appropriate answer in this particular situation, since it uses `beamer` methods, and is independent of the code inside the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames, professionalfonts,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,arrows}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\draw[use as bounding box](8,1) circle [radius=1.081];
\draw[fill] (15.5,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw[] (8,-2) circle [radius=1.08];

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[use as bounding box] (8,1) circle [radius=1.081];
\draw[fill] (15.5,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw[] (8,-2) circle [radius=1.08];

\draw[dashed] (15.5,0) circle [radius=7.515];
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you both @AlanMunn and Kevin C. These are both very helpful!

Comment: Is it necessary to load `graphics` too? I think TikZ automatically loads `graphicx`

Comment: @KevinC No, you're right, it's not necessary (although harmless, since `graphicx` loads `graphics` itself).

Comment: @Thomas I think you should accept KevinC's answer over mine.  Mine is more `tikz` oriented, but Kevin's is more `beamer` oriented, and for your particular problem I think his is the better solution.

Comment: @AlanMunn `beamer` deactivates the floating mechanism, so there's no problem using `figure` (it only will not float). Using  `figure` has one possible advantage: it allows the use of `\caption` (I am not a fan of captions in presentations but some people might find this useful).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Clearly my `beamer` knowledge is deficient. :) I see that the use of `figure` in a presentation is also useful for including true floats in `article` mode.

Comment: @AlanMunn yes, that's perhaps the most useful feature of allowing `figure` and `table` in presentations.